# Error con math.sqrt() en Python: ValueError: math domain error

Tags: python

He hecho un programa para ecuaciones de 2.º grado:

```
import math
print()
print("****Fórmula para ecuación de 2º Grado****")
print()
a = int(input("Introduzca primer miembro ="))
b = int(input("Introduzca segundo miembro ="))
c = int(input("Introduzca tercer miembro ="))
y = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
math.sqrt(y)
r = math.sqrt(b ** 2 - 4 * a * c)
print(r)
x = (-b + r) / (2 * a)
print(x)
pause = input()
```

Sin embargo, me sale este error:

```
error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/USUARIO/PycharmProjects/PY1/Ecuacion.py", line 9, in <module>
    math.sqrt(y) ValueError: math domain error
```

¿Cuál es el error que estoy cometiendo?

Comment: Edita la pregunta para que se vea mejor el código

Comment: el tema es que no se puede hacer raiz cuadrada de un negativo pone un if antes preguntando si es negativo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si mal no recuerdo, la formula cuadrática solo devuelve un valor real cuando la parte interior de la raíz cuadrada es positiva.

No sé que valores estes probrando, pero el error se debe a que

```
math.sqrt(y)
```

esta evaluando un numero negativo. Busca un ejemplo en internet ya hecho y veras que funciona bien.

Una alternativa es usar un `try` para estar preparado ante estos errores

```
try:
    math.sqrt(y)
except:
    print "Los numeros no son validos"
```

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme, Kenny!

Comment: De nada @Manulike. Que bueno que obtuviste ayuda. He visto en los otros comentarios que has usado un try. Si te ha servido mi respuesta puedes marcarla como aceptada con el cheque abajo del puntaje. Esto ayuda a los usuarios del sitio a saber que respuesta te ha ayudado mas. Si esta en tus posibilidades, participa activamente en el sitio y recomiendalo. No olvides leer todo lo que puedas del [help].

Answer (score 7):

La función `math.sqrt()` sólo funciona para argumentos positivos.

Puedes comprobar en tu código si `y` es positiva antes de intentar calcular la raíz. Si no lo es, la ecuación no tiene soluciones reales:

```
import math
print()
print("****Fórmula para ecuación de 2º Grado****")
print()
a = int(input("Introduzca primer miembro ="))
b = int(input("Introduzca segundo miembro ="))
c = int(input("Introduzca tercer miembro ="))
y = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
if y<0:
    print("La ecuación no tiene soluciones reales")
else:
    r = math.sqrt(y)
    print(r)
    x = (-b + r) / (2 * a)
    print(x)
    # Te faltó también imprimir la otra solución
    x = (-b - r) / (2 * a)
    print(x)
pause = input()
```

Otra posibilidad es utilizar el módulo `cmath` en lugar de `math`. Este módulo permite cálculos con números complejos, por lo que aún si no hay solución real a la ecuación podrías obtener su solución compleja:

```
import cmath
print()
print("****Fórmula para ecuación de 2º Grado****")
print()
a = int(input("Introduzca primer miembro ="))
b = int(input("Introduzca segundo miembro ="))
c = int(input("Introduzca tercer miembro ="))

y = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
r = cmath.sqrt(y)
x = (-b + r) / (2 * a)
print(x)
x = (-b - r) / (2 * a)
print(x)

pause = input()
```

Este método en cambio queda "feo" si la solución es real, pues en cualquier caso te la mostrará como compleja (si bien con la parte imaginaria igual a 0).

Un detalle adicional, yo usaría `float(input(...))` en lugar de `int(input(...))`, pues ¿por qué han de ser enteros los coeficientes de la ecuación?

Comment: En vez de responder lo mismo unos minutos despues, siempre puedes tratar de mejorar la respuesta que ya sabes que esta correcta ;D Ya sabes, para darle oportunidad a otros. :D

Comment: @KennyBarrera Hum... percibo un tono negativo en tu comentario a pesar de los emoticonos. No he respondido "lo mismo", pues tú proponías manejar excepciones mientras que yo planteo verificar el signo del argumento, ya sabes, el debate entre  "pedir permiso, o pedir disculpas". Además añado cómo hallar las soluciones complejas. Además ya estaba escribiendo mi respuesta cuando apareció la tuya, y vi que eran lo suficientemente diferentes. Además, no tengo por qué justificarme ;-)

Comment: Aunque la pregunta fue un poco editada, el OP pide que le digan cual es la causa del error. En ambas respuestas, en las primeras lineas, se indica claramente esto: math.sqrt no admite valores negativos. Esa es la respuesta correcta, no hay mas. Lo que viene después es un añadido, que muchos de nosotros escribimos para darle valor agregado a la pregunta, lo cual me parece muy positivo, así que, esa es la razón de mi comentario. Hey, al final solo fue un comentario, nada de malas vibras por mi parte. Éxitos en todo y hay que seguir ayudando a todos por acá.

Comment: @KennyBarrera Lo cierto es que cuando yo respondí la pregunta decía "¿Alguien puede ayudarme?" en vez de "¿Cuál es el error que estoy cometiendo?", y en ese sentido al ver que mi respuesta proporcionaba formas de resolver el problema diferentes de la tuya, decidí publicarla de todas formas. Disculpa si me pareció entrever negatividad en tu comentario inicial. ¡A seguir ayudando y colaborando!. 

Comment: Gracias, abulafia, una pregunta: me pone que "fedorqui" ha editado mi pregunta, ¿Por eso dices que la pregunta cambió?

Comment: ¿Y es que las personas con muchas medallas pueden hacer eso?

Comment: Soy nuevo por eso no entiendo del tema, gracias de antemano :)

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿Hay alguna forma de que cmath no salga así: (5+0j)?

Comment: @Manulike Sí, muchos de los usuarios de este sitio podemos editar preguntas para mejorar detalles de formato, ortografía, y en general mejorar la claridad de lo que se pregunta. Depende de los puntos de reputación (no medallas :-) Los resultados de `cmath` salen así porque son complejos, aún si sólo tienen parte real. Puedes evitarlo por ejemplo mirando el signo de `y`. Si es positivo, usas `r = math.sqrt(y)` y si es negativo usas `r = cmath.sqrt(y)`, luego ya sigues igual. De ese modo, si hay soluciones reales, el resultado sreá real y si no complejo.

Comment: @Manulike Otra cosa, no conviene extender demasiado la zona de comentarios. Lo digo porque tus cuatro comentarios anteriores podrían haberse escrito en uno solo :-) Puedes editar un comentario en los primeros cinco minutos tras escribirlo. Después de eso ya solo puedes borrarlo.

Comment: @abulafia Gracias por tus consejos, al final lo he hecho con try y except: si ponías un número negativo daba error y como tengo un menú con fórmulas (área de cuadrado/ rectángulo, triángulo, circunferencia) lo incluiré en él. 
Gracias por tu ayuda, no esperaba que la gente fuera tan amable :)

Comment: Si la respuesta de @KennyBarrera fue la que finalmente te sirvió, deberías marcarla como "aceptada" para señalar eso y subir su reputación. Haz clic en la marca ✔️junto a su respuesta.

Comment: @abulafia Gracias, pero tú también me ayudaste mucho con cmath y los 2 resultados, pondré la marca. Adiós